# Schedule jobs in Gearman

Tags: python-3.x, gearman

I want to schedule a job in [Gearman](http://gearman.org/). I found some options like SUBMIT_JOB_SCHED and SUBMIT_JOB_EPOCH from Gearman protocol documentation [here](http://gearman.org/protocol/). But I did not find any implementation on any existing Gearman server.

Is it possible to schedule a job in Gearman? Is there any example that I can refer to? (prefer python)

I also found with a persistent Gearman queue, there is a column called when_to_run INT from [here](http://gearman.org/manual/job_server/#libdrizzle). I put the epoch time directly in the database column and tried without luck.

Please help if you have done this, that is scheduled a job in Gearman for a specific date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Gearmand does not currently support this feature. The GitHub issue https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues/101 tracks this. As a workaround, one of the current maintainers of gearmand has suggested using `atd` to schedule the submission of jobs at specific times. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command) for more information.